# How to add all children from all parents using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a list of categories and for each category I have a list of products, so that when I need to know how many products for each category I use the below query inside my Category (parent) repository:

```
@Query("select size(c.products) from Category c where c.id=:parentID")
Long countProducts(@Param("parentID") UUID parentID);
```

However, I'm not sure what to do now that I need to get the total combined for all the products inside all these categories. I was wondering if I should use the child Product repository and query things there instead and if that's the best way to do this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could use `ProductRepository.count()`, it returns the total amount of all products. Pay attention, however that this approach suits you only in case your schema prohibits Products not bound to a Category.

In the opposite case (a Product exists without bound Category) you could try something like this:

```java
  @Query(value =
         " select count(p) " +
         " from PRODUCT p " +
         " join CATEGORY c on c.ID = p.CATEGORY_ID", nativeQuery = true)
  long countAllProducts();
```